# Alfresco Workflow update programmatically a task

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I try to edit a task programmatically

My problem is to know for a specific task, which fields are allowed to be modified or not

For exemple, I have a task like this

```
[properties] => Array
(
[bpm_percentComplete] => 0
[bpm_description] => ma description
[bpm_hiddenTransitions] => Array
(
)

[bpm_package] => workspace://SpacesStore/33ae7716-1697-413e-bd0c-033efcd13f16
[bpm_dueDate] =>
[bpm_context] => workspace://SpacesStore/fb976941-d7bb-44a8-8c03-263c353fff4c
[bpm_priority] => 2
[bpm_taskId] => 13798
[bpm_reassignable] => 1
[bpm_startDate] => 2014-10-06T09:04:48.000+02:00
[bpm_completedItems] =>
[bpm_pooledActors] => Array
(
)

[bpm_status] => Not Yet Started
[bpm_comment] =>
[wf_reviewOutcome] => Reject
[bpm_completionDate] =>
[bpm_packageActionGroup] =>
[bpm_outcomePropertyName] => wf:reviewOutcome
[cm_content] =>
[bpm_packageItemActionGroup] => edit_package_item_actions
[cm_created] => 2014-10-06T09:04:48.000+02:00
[bpm_outcome] =>
[cm_name] => wf:activitiReviewTask
[cm_owner] => sjeandroz
)
```

I would like to know (programmatically) which fields are "Technicaly fields" (for exemple cm_name or bpm_taskId), which one are editable fields (for exemple bpm_status or bpm_comment) and which one cannot be modified (like bpm_description)

Thanks in advanced and sorry for my bad english

Sylvain

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you need to get a list of the form properties defined for the task.
The easiest way to do this is to use the formService to retrieve the form data for the task.

ActivitiUtil.getFormService().getTaskFormData(taskId);

This will return the form key, the deployment id and the form properties defined for the task.

Comment: Hi Greg,
Thanks for your response!
I can't find a method to get the TaskFormData in other way than Java. If possible I prefere coding using Javascript API or Php using REST api. So using REST API I am able to get a Taskformmodel (https://api.alfresco.com/yourcompany.com/public/workflow/versions/1/tasks/152/task-form-model) but no way to get the TaskFormData...

Do you know if there is the same method getTaskFormData() but in Javascript or using REST ?  THanks a lot! and sorry for my bad english

Comment: If we could request activiti directly without request alfresco, we could call the url "service/form/form-data?taskId=:taskId" but I don't know if we can request activiti without request alfresco...

Comment: Hi Sylvain, I don't believe Alfresco exposes the standard Activiti REST endpoints out of the box. However, I was under the impression that the more recent releases of Alfresco expose some sort of Workflow RESP API directly. Worst case, you could create an extension to the API.